# Microsoft translate using python?

Tags: python, translate

I'm using the default Microsoft python library to translate text but every time I tried it it give error

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This simple app uses the '/translate' resource to translate text from
# one language to another.

# This sample runs on Python 2.7.x and Python 3.x.
# You may need to install requests and uuid.
# Run: pip install requests uuid

import os, requests, uuid, json

key_var_name = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'
if not key_var_name in os.environ:
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(key_var_name))
subscription_key = os.environ[key_var_name]

endpoint_var_name = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT'
if not endpoint_var_name in os.environ:
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(endpoint_var_name))
endpoint = os.environ[endpoint_var_name]

# If you encounter any issues with the base_url or path, make sure
# that you are using the latest endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate
path = '/translate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&from=en&to=de&to=it'
constructed_url = endpoint + path + params

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

# You can pass more than one object in body.
body = [{
    'text' : 'Hello World!'
}]
request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

after adding the secret key and the endpoint provided by azure i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\seto\Codes\Python\translation\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(key_var_name))
Exception: Please set/export the environment variable:
```

Comment: in cmd.exe, are you able to verify content via `echo %TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY%` and `echo %TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT%`? Obviously don't post the contents here, but just a sanity check

Comment: when i tried echo %TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY% it prints %TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY% no values

Comment: Then you need to setup those environment variables with the required values. You also probably need to subscribe to the service (paid or free) and get an API key corresponding for it.

Comment: i already registered and got the secert key
how to set those environment variables in windows ?
i tried through the advanced setting from my computer and added them but the problem still present

Answer (score 0):

i managed to resolve it by removing the environment variables and just use local variables

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This simple app uses the '/translate' resource to translate text from
# one language to another.

# This sample runs on Python 2.7.x and Python 3.x.
# You may need to install requests and uuid.
# Run: pip install requests uuid

import os, requests, uuid, json

key_var_name = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
subscription_key = key_var_name

endpoint_var_name = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/'
endpoint = endpoint_var_name

# If you encounter any issues with the base_url or path, make sure
# that you are using the latest endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate
path = '/translate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&from=en&to=ar'
constructed_url = endpoint + path + params

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': "francecentral",
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

# You can pass more than one object in body.
body = [{
    'text' : 'Hello World!'
}]
request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()
```